# Align commandButton to the right in Primefaces 10

Tags: primefaces

In Primefaces 8, I had a form like this:

[image: pf8commandButton]

After Primefaces 10 update, most of the components' aligns were moved, and I fixed them, but I couldn't manage to move the commandButton to the right side. The same commandButton in PF 8.0 looks like this in PF 10.0:

[image: pf10commandButton]

I tried these, but did not work:

```
<p:commandButton style="float:right;"/>
------------------
<div align="right">
      <button/>
</div>
------------------
<div class="ui-grid-col-4 TexAlCenter" style="text-align: right;">
```

xhtml code of commandButton:

```
<p:row>                        
  <div class = "ui-grid-col-4 TexAlCenter">
    <p:commandButton id = "CB_add" 
                     rendered = "someController.rendered()"
                     class = "cb-form Fright ResponsiveCB"
                     action = "#{someController.add()}"
                     global = "true"
                     process = "@this :F_experience"
                     update = ":PGROUP_form :PGROUP_content"
                     value = "Add"
                     icon = "icon-plus" />
  </div>
  <div class = "ui-grid-col-4 TexAlCenter">
    <p:commandButton id = "CB_update"
                     rendered = "someController.rendered()"
                     class = "cb-form Fright ResponsiveCB"
                     action = "#{someController.update()}"
                     global = "true"
                     process = "@this :F_experience"
                     update = ":PGROUP_form :PGROUP_content"
                     value = "Update"
                     icon = "icon-pencil" />
  </div>
  <div class = "ui-grid-col-4 TexAlCenter">
    <p:commandButton id = "CB_cancel"
                     class = "cb-form Fright ResponsiveCB"
                     action = "#{someController.cancel()}"
                     global = "true"
                     process = "@this"
                     update = ":PGROUP_form :PGROUP_content"
                     value = "Cancel"
                     icon = "icon-cancel">
        <p:resetInput target = "@form" />
    </p:commandButton>
  </div>
  <p:defaultCommand target="CB_add" />
  <p:defaultCommand target="CB_update" />
</p:row>
```

Comment: @JasperdeVries I tried this method too, but it didn't work. These buttons are inside the panelGrid, could that be the reason? 

<p:panelGrid columns = "2" class = "BordNone OvHidden TabLayFixed Wid100" columnClasses = "ui-grid-col-3 TexAlRight ResTexAlRight,ui-grid-col-9" layout = "grid" styleClass = "ui-panelgrid-blank">

Comment: Try `display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;` no a wrapper div.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thank you but did not work. When I take it inside <ui:fragment> and the classes of commandButtons are "cb-form Fright ResponsiveCB WidAuto", it comes where I want, but it works when I take it outside the panelGrid. This time it stays outside the table.

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve]. I tested this and it works for me (as well as text-align right).

Comment: @JasperdeVries okay, I solved it as changing rows to ui:fragment and putting <p:outputLabel /> above ui:fragment so its shifts buttons to the right now.